# iPhone/Objective C - Executing Code without a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have a simple function which I wish to execute in objective c. I am using xcode and this is just a dummy application which requires no view. I have been told never to change the main method..so the question arises, how can I execute this function. the function is stored in a simple objective c class in the classes folder and I am using a window based project....

Thanks

Comment: Executing code without view ? Sounds like just a basic objective-c compilation and running , and not iPhone related.

Comment: its the start of an iphone app, but its so early on there's no need for the view. Where should I execute the code?

Comment: Hm. You can just execute the code, there is a section in xcode which has displays output, and provides details such as `NSLogs` and stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the file (header if it has one) into the App Delegate; in the `applicationDidFinishLoading:` method: create an instance of the class the function is in (assuming its not a class method (starts with a + instead of a -)); and call the function on your created instance, you may want to NSLog the return value if there is one.

Something like this in your appdelegate.m

```
#import "Appdelegate.h"
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation AppDelegate 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
MyClass *testClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSString *result = [myClass testFunction]; //initialize and include paramaters if need be, etc etc. also whatever you return should be what result is, obviously
NSLog (@"My result: %@", result);

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call your function in the method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: which is in your application delegate file.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you want to *write the Model part of the **MVC architecture** first :D*. Anyways you can always have that app without view and the entry point for any application is application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of your delegate.

If you just want to write a objective C program and still want to use xcode you can create a empty project and write your classes and methods just like any other objective-c program. You can also specify build options in xcode.